# onmessage in web workers can not access class variable

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I am making multithreading file uploading .

when I access to Class variable in `myWorker.onmessage`, it shows error.

```js
app.4c7f2a2a.js:32 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at a.onmessage
```

How can I solve this error ?

check my source code.

```js
// queue.js
class Queue {
    constructor() {
        this.items = [];
        this.size = -1;
    }
    sendChunk( chunkId) {
        if (window.Worker) {
            const myWorker = new Worker("/worker.js");
            myWorker.postMessage([chunkId]);
            myWorker.onmessage = function (e) {
                console.log(e.data);
                console.log(this.size); // <-- this make error
            }
        }
    }
}
export default Queue;
```

```js
// worker.js
onmessage = async function (e) {
    const count = e.data[0];
    const data = {
        count: count,
        local_time: new Date().toLocaleTimeString(),
    };

    fetch('/time', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        })
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
            postMessage(JSON.stringify(data));
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
}
```

```js
// main.js
import Queue from './queue';
const q = new Queue();
q.startQueue();
```

`console.log(this.size);`  makes error.

Comment: you don't appear to be calling your `onmessage` function;  rather, it appears as you are trying to re-define it.

Comment: @Claies Can you explain  more in detail? . I think I followed MDN guide.

Comment: reading your code again, I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to accomplish;  your `onmessage` is defined in `worker.js` as an event listener, there really shouldn't be a reason that `sendChunk` would directly interact with it.....

Comment: @Claies Yes you are right.  I fixed it as  `        myWorker.onmessage = (e) => {
                console.log(e.data);
                let obj = JSON.parse(e.data);
            }
`  It works properly.  And How can I set your comment as a answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` will be within the scope of the `onmessage` function. If you need to use the class variables within the callback of `onmessage` then, you can store `this` into some other variable like `that` in the example below and then access the members within.

```
// queue.js
class Queue {
    constructor() {
        this.items = [];
        this.size = -1;
    }
    sendChunk( chunkId) {
        if (window.Worker) {
            const myWorker = new Worker("/worker.js");
            myWorker.postMessage([chunkId]);
            const that = this
            myWorker.onmessage = function (e) {
                console.log(e.data);
                console.log(that.size);
            }
        }
    }
}
export default Queue;
```